# How to store group attributes (for authorization) in LDAP

Tags: architecture, ldap

I'm new to LDAP and looking at modelling product permissions for authorization within LDAP.  Thanks to many great articles on the web, I now know how to specify group membership using roles/GroupOfNames, however what is the best practice for storing attribute values associated with the group membership?

For example, If I want to say a user has access to products A, B & C, I can create 3 groups and allocate the user as a member of each group.   However now I want to say that among other permissions, the user has read access for A, write access for B, and that for group C - their favourite color is Green & the user's codename is "1234".

Is it appropriate to create a separate heirachy for each group membership with a custom schema for each group membership?

Ie:

`dc=company, dc=com
  ou=Users
    uid = 1;
  ou=Products
    uid=A (members=1)
    uid=B (members=1)
    uid=C (members=1)
  ou=Permissions
    ou=ProductA
      uid=1, Access=Read
    ou=ProductB
      uid=1, Access=Write
    ou=ProductC

      uid=1, FavColour=Green, codename=1234`

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

LDAP atttributes can't have attributes, so you can't have a product with a member attribute which in turn has a 'read' or 'write' attribute.

You might have to add subtrees for Read and Write under each product, such that the user's memberhip of `<product>` gives him basic access, whatever that is, or maybe even nothing, and membership of `<product>/Read` adds read access: similarly for write.

Your question about group C has nothing to do with authorization, and I would say it is outside the scope of LDAP completely. I would put that in a database. LDAP is great for what it's for but very difficult to bend to other purposes. You can use it for anything hierarchical with great ease, but that doesn't look anything like an LDAP case to me.

Comment: Thanks for being the only person to respond!  I was hoping for some comment on my proposed solution.  Is it a bad idea?  Is it more or less efficient compared to just creating individual groups as you suggest?  Whilst my example is simplified, we have about 50 permissions split over about 10 product (groups).  If you could perhaps extend your comments then the bounty is yours!